# Push notification for azure notification hub

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, azure-active-directory

I have configured push notification through azure notification hub and its working for both my android and ios device. The question is Do I need to configure a back end to be able to send notifications or I can keep using the test send under the notification hub to push my notifications, any limitations to using the test send? Is the test send only for testing?

Comment: You can’t use the test send if you’re wanting automated notifications based on some sort of event. The only way to do that would be to use something like UiPath but that’s just silly. Look at implementing an Azure function to catch your event and send the notification. The SDK for notification hubs is where you need to start. I implemented that same sort of approach around a year ago and it works for me. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to configure a back end to be able to send notifications

Yes, Push notifications are normally sent in a back-end service like Mobile Apps or ASP.NET using a compatible library. If a library is not available for your back-end you can also use the [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495827.aspx) directly to send notification messages.

For sending cross-platform notifications, you can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-cross-platform-notification).

> Is the test send only for
>   testing?

Yes, the test send in Azure portal is only for testing.